# Sum of the inverse element geometric sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need assistance with the following question: 
 
$a_1,a_2,....,a_{10} $  are terms of geometric sequence, show formula for the sum of:
$\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+....+\frac{1}{a_{10}}$

I tried to,
lowest common denominator and got:
$\frac{(a_2a_3...a_{10})+(a_1a_3...a_{10})+...+(a_1a_3...a_{9})}{a_1a_2....a_{10}}=$ 
 $\frac{(a_2a_3...a_{10})+(a_1a_3...a_{10})+...+(a_1a_3...a_{9})}{a_1^{10}qq^2q^3....q^9}$.

 but the result should be $\frac{(q^{10}-1)}{a_1q^9(q-1)}$

how they got this answer ?

Comment: $(a_j)_1^{10}$ is a geometric sequence, i.e. $a_{n+1}/ a_n$ is a constant. You can similarly investigate $(1/a_j)_1^{10}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dfrac{1}{a_1}+...+\dfrac{1}{a_{10}}=\dfrac{1}{a_1}+\dfrac{1}{qa_1}+\dfrac{1}{q^2a_1}+...+\dfrac{1}{q^{9}a_1}=\dfrac{1}{a_1}\bigg(1+\dfrac{1}{q}+...+\dfrac{1}{q^9}\bigg)$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** : Factor out by the first term, and consider the sequence $u_n = 1/(q^n)$. You should find a result in the form $\sum_k u^k = \frac{u^{n+1}-1}{u-1}$.